# Customize the Vaadin Slider

Tags: vaadin

I'd like to customize the data showed by the slider. For example instead of showing a number it should say "prefix" + number + "suffix", also this value should always be visible.

In the class VSlider I have found the method `public void setFeedbackValue(double value)`. I suspect this is where the values showed by the slider is configured. I have tried to copy the class in my own project with the same package structure and I've also recompiled the widgetset but the changes aren't showed in the view. I'm new to creating client side code for Vaadin so there might be something that I didn't understand correctly.

**Questions:**

Do you have any suggetions on how I could implement what I want?

Do you know why copying the `VSlider` class and changing it didn't work?

Thanks

Comment: Why dont you use the "Slider" class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up creating a new slider by copying the classes from the Vaadin framework related to the Slider e.g. Slider, VSlider and SliderConnector.
Then I could change the code in VSlider however I wanted.

Comment: Hi, how can we use your slider? Is there any slider in VAADIN with an opportunity for setting interval or step?